# Can I use Corolla theme as a fixed width layout?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a fresh install of D7 and have downloaded Corolla theme.

I go into appearance and set the page width from 100% to 944px, which works fine, but, whenever I resize the browser window, the first sidebar breaks and drops to the left of the page. I would like it to just display a horizontal scrollbar.

Is there anyway to modify this theme to do this?

Comment: Have you set the sidebar width to a fixed width as well?

Comment: yeah a fixed width in pixels.

Comment: As Danny pointed out, this is very specifically the intended behaviour. In theory you can ofcourse override it, but it's an uphill battle. If you don't want a responsive theme, install a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I have not used that theme myself, it indicates on the project page that it's 'Responsive' so the sidebar is doing what its supposed to do when the browser is resized to a narrower width -- it's using a Media Query. I tried the demo and this was my experience as well. Though that might have seemed odd in the old days, now it's actually what you want for the site to work with multiple devices and screen widths. You will note that if you resize even narrower, the other sidebar goes underneath as well and this is as expected.

From the project page:

> "The new 7.x-2.x version is a subtheme of Adaptivetheme which includes
>   a powerful new responsive layout engine with full support for mobile
>   devices."

You may want to take a look at this for a primer on Responsive Design: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: yeah I get that, I was just wondering if there was a simple way to change this behaviour but I guess not. It sux because I really like the style of the theme and would use it it I could easily change that but its probably going to take as much time as finding/modifying another theme altogether.